# How to get a diff of commit ID with previous commit if I don't know which one was previous

Tags: git

I obtained a git commit ID using `git log --grep=<someregex>`

Repository has over 600 000 commits and this one is old several months. How can I do a simple git diff that would show the changes made by this commit compared with previous commit, so that I would only see changes made by this commit?

git diff  give me diff of this to latest one which results in quadrillions of lines and crash whole git...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could view exactly what the commit did by doing `git show <sha>`. Alternatively, if you positively have to use `git diff`, you can use the `^` syntax: `git diff <sha>^..<sha>`.